# How to output environment content to a file while enclosing content by a box?

Tags: environments, xml, write-file

This is the source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{obj}{name-of-obj}
This is a test code.
\begin{equation}
a < b
\end{equation}
\end{obj}
\end{document}
```

I want to enclose the content of obj by a box.
Using `framed` package, it is possible by defining:

```
\newenvironment{obj}[1]{%
\begin{framed}
}{%
\end{framed}
}
```

However, at the same time, I want to generate xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<obj name="name-of-obj">
<content mime="application/x-latex"><![CDATA[
This is a test code.
\begin{equation}
a < b
\end{equation}
]]></content>
</obj>
</root>
```

(It seems VerbatimOut in `fancyvrb` realizes xml output but it spoils usual dvi output.)

How can I implement this feature?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Maybe with the environ package?  You get the body of any environment instance in one convenient \BODY macro which you can then process in multiple ways.  You probably can't process it in true verbatim mode though, as it will have already been parsed to some extent.

Comment: I'd also look into the `extract` package.

Comment: Thank you, @Claudio, for your considerate guide to great introduction to the site. It helped me a lot.  Thank you, @Andrew, for your helpful comment. As you say, I was not able to use `\BODY` macro to solve my problem.  Thank you, @mbork, for your telling me interesting package. It seems usable for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\objout
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{obj}[1]
{%
\fbox{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\BODY}}%
\immediate\openout\objout=#1.xml
\immediate\write\objout{%
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>^^J%
<obj name="name-of-obj">%^^J
<content mime="application/x-latex"><![CDATA[^^J%
\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}^^J%
]]></content>^^J%
</obj>^^J%
</root>^^J%
}%
\immediate\closeout\objout
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{obj}{name-of-obj}
This is a test code.
\begin{equation}
a < b
\end{equation}
\end{obj}
\end{document}
```

Typesets the content in a box and writes out `name-of-obj.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <root>
<obj name="name-of-obj"><content mime="application/x-latex"><![CDATA[
This is a test code. \begin {equation} a < b \end {equation}
]]></content>
</obj>
</root>
```

Note line endings have been lost in the saved file. Normally that doesn't matter, if it does, then trickier, more fragile,  versions involving catcode changes would be needed.

It also doesn't check for `]]>` appearing in the content.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your quick and great answer! It worked very well with a little modification. `]]>` problem is so nitpicky that I don't care for now.